# Linphone crash on network switch in android sometime

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

Sometime on network switch Linphone app getting crash, error coming from ndk.

Suppose i am on call and network switch from Wifi to data network then some time it crash.

Below is error

```
  
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] local reference table dump:
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]   Last 10 entries (of 511):
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       510: 0x12dfb530 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       509: 0x13c62200 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCallImpl
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       508: 0x12dfb530 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       507: 0x13c621e0 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCallImpl
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       506: 0x12dfb530 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       505: 0x12dfb470 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       504: 0x12dfb470 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       503: 0x12dfb470 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       502: 0x12dfb470 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       501: 0x12dfb470 org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]   Summary:
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       103 of org.linphone.core.LinphoneCall$State (2 unique instances)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       200 of org.linphone.core.LinphoneCore$RegistrationState (1 unique instances)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]         2 of org.linphone.core.LinphoneCallImpl (2 unique instances)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]       200 of org.linphone.core.LinphoneProxyConfigImpl (2 unique instances)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]         2 of java.lang.Class (2 unique instances)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]         1 of java.lang.String[] (3 elements)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127]         3 of java.lang.String (3 unique instances)
 A/art: art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:127] 
 A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
 A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
 A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] 
 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10751 (messenger.debug)
```

Comment: What is your question? What's the cause of the crash? How to fix? Something else?

Comment: Actually i dont know the excet reason but in crash report i found the reference overflow issue and it happen network switch but very rare. but happen in once in two day or a day